# Eclipse - "Launching 'KeyInPlaintext' Debug has encountered a problem. Error starting process."

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, compilation, cygwin

I am currently attempting to compile and run a C program in eclipse.  The problem is, every time I attempt to run a program, the same error shows up.

[The image shows the error that is displayed.  I am not sure what to get out of that error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdO4k.png)

I currently have cygwin installed, and am able to run gcc and g++ on the command prompt.  I also have PE Windows Parser and Cygwin PE parser enabled under Binary Parsers.  I have also cleaned and built the project many times over.

Comment: in general,  Need to 'compile' the program, then 'link' the program, then try to run the file that is the result of the 'link' step,   In the case referenced, the program to run is: `keyinplaintext.exe`, NOT `KeyInPlaintext.c`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you mean to "build" the project before running?  Or are there buttons in eclipse that are specific to "compile" and "link"?  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes, in Eclipse, use the menu: 'project' 'build all'   However, be sure that the 'project' 'properties' then: c/c__build'  (and associated sub tabs) has everything set up correctly for the compiler you are using. then, for the middle tabs for 'GCC C Compiler' and 'GCC C Linker' and 'GCC Asssembler'   be sure that each of the fields are set up correctly.  If you have questions about what each field should contain, ask me.

Comment: can you execute 'gcc' from the command line to compile, then link?  If so, then the 'gcc' tool chain is setup correctly and the problem is in the set up of Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, gcc is able to compile and link. I am able to get a .exe file when compiling from the command prompt.  I am also under the suspicion that Eclipse is set up improperly.  Should the makefile be in the same directory as the source (.c) files, or can they be in another location?  I imagine that eclipse uses the makefiles it generated when building.